# HttP Post method is not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use this method i also tried to impot libriries but all in vain. Kindly help me. Not any HTTPClient library is showing on my andriod studio. Help would be appreciated

```
 public String getHttpPost(String url,ContentValues) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) { // Status OK
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Did you add the dependencies in your gradle file?

Comment: did you add Internet permission in AndroidManifeast.xml

Comment: do you want another method to make the networking call, example, using Library like volley or Retrofit?

Comment: yes i have added all

Answer (score 0):

Oh!Still you are using HttpClient.You can use HttpURLConnection,Volley etc. HttpClient class is now deprecated.Also add Internet permission, and dependensies in gradle file.

```
 HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                try {
                    URL urlToRequest = new URL(_url);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(30000);
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                    if (_authenticationKey != null) {
                        urlConnection.setRequestProperty(_authenticationKey, _authenticationValue);
                    }
                    if (_jsonPacket != null) {
                        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                        wr.write(_jsonPacket);
                        wr.flush();
                    }

                    int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                    JSONObject job;
                    if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream());
                        String responseString = getResponseString(in);
                        if (isJSONValid(responseString)) {
                            job = new JSONObject(responseString);
                            return new PostingResult(job, Constants.IntegerConstants.failureFromWebService, "");
                        } else {
                            return new PostingResult(null, statusCode, Constants.StringConstants.serverCommunicationFailed + "Response code = " + statusCode);
                        }

                    } else {
                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                        String responseString = getResponseString(in);
                        if (isJSONValid(responseString)) {
                            job = new JSONObject(responseString);
                            return new PostingResult(job, Constants.IntegerConstants.success, "");
                        } else {
                            return new PostingResult(null, statusCode, Constants.StringConstants.serverCommunicationFailed + Constants.StringConstants.serverReadingResponseFailed);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I have added INTERNET permission and also add dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Volley" library to make network call.

eg.

1. Add this line in build.gradle (Module:app)

   compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
2. As you are making network call you need internet permission. So add Internet permission line in Manifest.xml

3. Now you need to write a small method inside your class where you need to make network call and need to pass Hashmap to it. Hashmap contains all your post parameters.

   ```
   private void getJSONResponse(HashMap<String, String> map, String url) {
           pd.show();
           JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(map), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   Log.d("Mayur", "Response : " + response);
                   //tv_res.setText(response.toString());
                   //pd.dismiss();
               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   //tv_res.setText("ERROR");
                   //pd.dismiss();
               }
           });
   request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);}
   ```

Now in your onCreate method or any other method just create a Hashmap of post parameters and pass it to this method with post url.

eg.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("fname", "Mayur");
        map.put("lname", "Thakur");
getJSONResponse(map,<your url>);
```